# Add a field in a many-to-one relation in NestJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to develop a small application to record cooking recipes. To do this, I declared 2 entities with nestJS allowing me to manage the recipes and another to manage the ingredients. I also created a 3rd entity to record the quantities of ingredients needed :

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eTGl.png)

```
// recipe.entity.js
@Entity()
export class Recipe {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column('datetime')
  createdAt: Date

  @Column('datetime')
  updatedAt: Date

  @Column('varchar', { length: 100 })
  title: string;

  @Column('varchar', {nullable: true})
  image: string;

  @OneToMany(type => RecipeIngredients, recipeIngredients => recipeIngredients.recipe)
  ingredients: RecipeIngredients[];
}
```

```
// ingredient.entity.js
@Entity()
export class Ingredient {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column('datetime')
  createdAt: Date

  @Column('datetime')
  updatedAt: Date

  @Column('varchar', { length: 100 })
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar', {nullable: true})
  image: string;

  @OneToMany(type => RecipeIngredients, recipeIngredients => recipeIngredients.ingredient)
  recipes: RecipeIngredients[];
}
```

```
// recipe_ingredients.entity.js
@Entity()
export class RecipeIngredients {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ManyToOne(type => Recipe, recipe => recipe.ingredients)
  recipe: Recipe

  @ManyToOne(type => Ingredient)
  ingredient: Ingredient

  @Column()
  quantity: string;
}
```

First, I would like to be able to retrieve a recipe with the list of necessary ingredients:

```
const recipe = await this.recipesRepository.createQueryBuilder('recipe')
    .where('recipe.id = :recipeId', {recipeId: _id})
    .leftJoin('recipe.ingredients', 'recipe_ingredients')
    .leftJoin('recipe_ingredients.ingredient', 'ingredient')
    .getMany();
```

But this method returns only my recipe object without the ingredients...

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "createdAt": "2020-04-30T09:12:22.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-04-30T09:12:22.000Z",
    "title": "Test",
    "image": null
  }
]
```

From there, I'm lost ... How can I get the list of my ingredients (at least the name and quantity fields) directly from my service?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `leftJoin` will able you to join data without its selection. It selects the recipe if it has ingredients, but won't return its ingredients.
As read in TypeORM's documentation :

> You can join data without its selection. To do that, use `leftJoin` or
>   `innerJoin`:
>
> ```
> const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
>     .innerJoin("user.photos", "photo")
>     .where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
>     .getOne();
> ```
>
> This will generate:
>
> ```
>  SELECT user.* FROM users user
>     INNER JOIN photos photo ON photo.user = user.id
>     WHERE user.name = 'Timber'
> ```
>
> This will select Timber if he has photos, but won't return his photos.

To select the ingredients try using `leftJoinAndSelect` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution solved my problem and allowed me to better understand!